# "Connection closed unexpectedly" VNC

Tags: linux, networking, vnc, ssh-tunnel, linode

I've been following NetworkChucks new video about setting up Kali linux on Linode and connecting through vnc viewer. When i try and actually connect to my server it says that the connection has closed unexpectedly. I think it has something to do with the error saying that vncserver@1 has failed but I'm new to vnc and linux in general and don't know what to do.
[Error in the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRndl.png)

This is the video I was following incase that helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLrfVMWT4AI

Comment: I had the same problem but I realized it was a problem related to disk space. You need to create a Linode with at least 80gb of disk space so Kali can be installed properly.

Answer (score -1):

I Faced the same issue while connecting to kali machine. This is because kali was not configured to work with VNC machine. You need to start kali machine from the marketplace rather than distribution.If you watch the first half of his video you would understand.